# Swift: pass navigation bar through presentViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem, presentviewcontroller

In my storyboard there are Navigation Controller, viewContrl1, and viewContrl2. For the next update, I have to make a way to segue viewContrl2 to another instance of viewContrl2.

After getting some helps from stackOverflow, I managed it via:

```
let newView2 : ViewContrl2 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewContrl2") as! ViewContrl2
...
...
view2.presentViewController(newView2, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It actually makes exactly what I want but without navigationBar on top.
In ViewContrl2 class, there is @IBOutlet weak var navigation: UINavigationItem!, which I directly connected from StoryBoard. However, it seems like the navigation is not working in newly created viewContrl2. I need this because users must be able to press go back and go back to previous view. Anyone have any solution to this problem?

Thank you

Comment: ViewContrl2 is subclass of UINavigationController?

Comment: Okay so... I am not familiar storyboard, but the relationship from Navigation Controller is "root view controller" to View1Control, then I called View2Contrl through push segue from View1Controller, and finally the new View2Control is called from view2Contrller through presentViewController. Navigation appear for view1Contrl and view2Contrl, but it wont even appear in the view2Contrl

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be able to go back, you need to use the existing Navigation controller.
Just add a checking just to make sure.

```
let newView2 : ViewContrl2 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewContrl2") as! ViewContrl2

if let navCtrl = self.navigationController
{
   navCtrl.pushViewController(newView2, animated: true)
}
else
{
   let navCtrl = UINavigationController(rootViewController: newView2)
   self.presentViewController(navCtrl, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Okay... So it actually work.
However, after all of my newViewController2 is loaded, it crashes right away, and I dont know why...

Answer (score 4):

If you want a `NavigationBar` to be seen, Please Present a `NavigationController` like Below:

```
let newView2 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewContrl2") as! ViewContrl2

let navigationControlr = UINavigationController(rootViewController: newView2)

self.presentViewController(navigationControlr, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

To Dismiss the `PresentedViewController` add the following code in `viewDidLoad`

```
//Customise the way you want:
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Cancel, target: self, action: "backAction")
```

add following `function` in your `ViewController2` Class

```
func backAction(){

    if self.presentingViewController != nil{
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }else{
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: It shows up, but it appeared to be disconnected from View1Control and View2Control's navigation. It shows go back button on top left, but it does not do anything. For example, in the situation of view2Control -> the new view2Control, if user presses go back in the newView2Controller, it must go back to view2Controller.

Comment: From this post I learned a lot. Your code must be working as well, but Chrsitian's answer seems more efficient so I used his. But I really appreciate for your help. Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome:) Anyway I thought you would want the presentation to keep and just get the navigation bar to the ViewController